# empty select on when another select is changued jquery

Tags: jquery, select

Hi I'm trying to empty an input select with this code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#firstselect', function(){
    if($('#secondselect').length > 1){
        $('#secondselect').empty();
        var html = '<option value="9997" selected="selected">ESCOJE UNA SUBCATEGORIA</option>'
        $('#subcategoria').html(html);
    }
});
```

Now it works fine with 0 but why if its 1 it does not?

Note: At first the select has the option that is shown which is added after is emptied and when the first select is changued it is filled with info from a server but I did not put that code since it's not relevant.

EDIT: It looks that if you do change to >= it does work but if it's >=2 does not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the length of the `select` element and not the number of `option` elements inside it. So there's only ever 1 select element that matches that ID.

```
if($('#secondselect option').length > 1) {
    // do stuff
```

Comment: thank you that's the answer I needed so you need to put the option selector so it checks the number of options! great answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '#firstselect', function(){
    if(($('#secondselect').length) >= 1){
        $('#secondselect').empty();
        var html = 'ESCOJE UNA SUBCATEGORIA'
        $('#subcategoria').html(html);
    }
});
```